# How to validate the downsampling is as intended

Tags: python, validation, signal-processing, resampling

how to validate whether the down sampled output is correct. For example, I had make some example, however, I am not sure whether the output is correct or not?

Any idea on the validation

Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # For ploting
from scipy import signal
import mne

fs = 100 # sample rate
rsample=50 # downsample frequency
fTwo=400 # frequency of the signal
x = np.arange(fs)
y = [ np.sin(2*np.pi*fTwo * (i/fs)) for i in x]
f_res = signal.resample(y, rsample)
xnew = np.linspace(0, 100, f_res.size, endpoint=False)
#
# ##############################
#
plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.stem(x, y)
plt.subplot(212)
plt.stem(xnew, f_res, 'r')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plotting the data is a good first take at a verification.  Here I made regular plot with the points connected by lines.  The lines are useful since they give a guide for where you expect the down-sampled data to lie, and also emphasize what the down-sampled data is missing.  (It would also work to only show lines for the original data, but lines, as in a stem plot, are too confusing, imho.)

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # For ploting
from scipy import signal

fs = 100 # sample rate
rsample=43 # downsample frequency
fTwo=13 # frequency of the signal
x = np.arange(fs, dtype=float)
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*fTwo * (x/fs))
print y
f_res = signal.resample(y, rsample)
xnew = np.linspace(0, 100, f_res.size, endpoint=False)
#
# ##############################
#
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.plot(xnew, f_res, 'or')
plt.show()
```

A few notes:

If you're trying to make a general algorithm, use non-rounded numbers, otherwise you could easily introduce bugs that don't show up when things are even multiples.  Similarly, if you need to zoom in to verify, go to a few random places, not, for example, only the start.

Note that I changed `fTwo` to be significantly less than the number of samples.  Somehow, you need at least more than one data point per oscillation if you want to make sense of it.

I also remove the loop for calculating `y`: in general, you should try to vectorize calculations when using numpy.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

The spectrum of the resampled signal should have a tone at the same frequency as the input signal just in a smaller nyquist bandwidth.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal
import scipy.fftpack as fft


fs = 100 # sample rate
rsample=50 # downsample frequency
fTwo=10 # frequency of the signal

n = np.arange(1024)
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*fTwo/fs*n)
y_res = signal.resample(y, len(n)/2)

Y = fft.fftshift(fft.fft(y))
f = -fs*np.arange(-512, 512)/1024
Y_res = fft.fftshift(fft.fft(y_res, 1024))
f_res = -fs/2*np.arange(-512, 512)/1024

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.stem(f, abs(Y))
plt.subplot(212)
plt.stem(f_res, abs(Y_res))
plt.show()
```

[image]

The tone is still at 10.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

IF you down sample a signal both signals will still have the exact same value and a given *time* , so just loop through "time" and check that the values are the same. In your case you go from a sample rate of 100 to 50. Assuming you have 1 seconds worth of data from building your x from fs, then just loop  through t = 0 to t=1 in 1/50'th increments and make sure that Yd(t) = Ys(t) where Yd d is the down sampled f and Ys is the original sampled frequency. Or to say it simply Yd(n) = Ys(2n)  for n = 1,2,3,...n=total_samples-1.

Comment: I agree with you, the value should be the same after down sample. However, as shown in the figure (using the attached code),  the value downsampled value is somewhat weird. Do you show with a sample code. Really appreciate it

Comment: What figure? I don't see any attached images

Comment: Also I am not familiar with you graph library but I would be suspicious about building your x and xnew differently. also seems weird that signal.resample doesn't need to know what the original sample frequency was? to downsample you would either need a ratio, or both original frequency AND sample length otherwise your equation isn't fully defined

Comment: It looks like your sample rate is less than the frequency of your signal.  fs = 100 but fTwo = 400.  So you are going to have aliasing from the beginning.

Comment: Yeah as I stated carefully to compare them at a given time. They will not match in the frequency domain